# how to change an url before to use on php

Tags: php, url, preg-replace

I have a function of a download parser, where the url of one site it's changed:
http://paste.co to https://controlc.com/

I can't change the url from a database, because aare encrypted.

```
class download_parser

{   
    private $container_domains  = '(?:tinypaste\\.com|tny\\.cz|controlc\\.com)';
    private $base_url           = '';
    private $package            = null;
    private $package_passwords  = array();
    public $current_password    = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        global $phpbb_root_path, $phpEx;
        include($phpbb_root_path . 'contributions/dlcapi/dlcapi.class.' . $phpEx);
    }

    public function set_base_url($url)
    {
        $this->base_url = preg_replace('#http[s]?://#i', '', $url);
        if(substr($this->base_url, -1) != '/')
        {
            $this->base_url .= '/';
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I need help to change the old url (pased.co) to the new one, before to decrypt the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_replace`

```
    public function set_base_url($url)
    {
        $this->base_url = preg_replace('#http[s]?://#i', '', $url);
        $this->base_url = preg_replace('#^paste\.co\b#', 'controlc.com', $this->base_url);
        if(substr($this->base_url, -1) != '/')
        {
            $this->base_url .= '/';
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but didn't work. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'download_parser' (T_STRING) on line 1 <?php

Comment: That doesn't seem to be related to my code, it's a problem with the code before the class definition.

Comment: Before the class code doesn’t exist nothing except the ?< anyway now it’s working when i put your code before the first set_base_url. Thanks!!!